# how to implement listener?

Tags: java, listener, openide

I have some dynamic tree. And now I need to implement some functionality, that happend every time, when simply click on node. (I mean only one click on node, which "makes it blue")

**EDIT2: ** I use beanTreeView and package openide

How to implement listener of this action?

EDIT - added pseudocode

```
public class MyNode extends AbstractNode{ //openide package
   private String name;

   public MyNode(String nameOfNode){
       super (new Children.LEAF);
       name = nameOfNode;
   }
   ....
   ....
}

public class IWantNameOfSelectedNode extends JPanel{   
    private JLabel jLnameOfNode;

   public IWantNameOfSelectedNode(){
       jLnameOfNode.setText("wiating for node selection");
   }
```

Now, I need put name of selected node to jLabel, and change it every time when selection of node changes.

Comment: maybe you already have some code from which we will start? at the moment can give you only link http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html with tutorial from sun (actually it should be enough)

Comment: In addition to what Roman said above, Once you understand listeners I would suggest checking into anonymous inner classes. 
http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.phpr/3300881/The-Essence-of-OOP-using-Java-Anonymous-Classes.htm
They can help make listeners a bit less annoying to implement IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Swing `JTree` class you should define a `TreeSelectionListener` and add it to the underlying `TreeModel`.  If you wish to use `ActionListener` instead you'll need to write some **adapter** code to translate `TreeSelectionEvent`s into `ActionEvent`s (although this would actually be fairly pointless).

**Example**

```
/**
 * Adapter class responsible for translating TreeSelectionEvents into
 * ActionEvents.
 */
public class TreeSelectionAdapter implements TreeSelectionListener {
  private final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger(0);
  // Prefer CopyOnWriteArrayList to avoid ConcurrentModificationException if an
  // ActionListener removes itself as a listener during notification.
  private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<ActionListener> listeners;

  public TreeSelectionAdapter() {
    this.listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<ActionListener();
  }

  public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
    this.listeners.add(l);
  }

  public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
    this.listeners.remove(l);
  }

  public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent evt) {
    // Create new ActionEvent which corresponds to incoming TreeSelectionEvent
    // and notify registered ActionListeners.
    ActionEvent aEvt = new ActionEvent(evt.getSource(),
      nextId.getAndIncrement(), "selectionChanged");

    for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
      listener.actionPerformed(listener);
    }
  }
}

TreeNode rootNode = createTreeModel(); // Create custom model
JTree tree = new JTree(rootNode); // Install model into JTree.

// Add adapter listener to underlying selection model.
tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(adapter);

// Register ActionListener with adapter listener.
adapter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    System.err.println("Selection has changed in some way!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is a Swing Tree. You could achieve this by using a CustomRenderer component or using a TreeSelectionListener interface.

This [link](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node155.html) has a tutorial for an advanced Example on how to alter the icons, backgrounds etc. What you need is a much simpler version than that.

The code you will be interested in is

```
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent( JTree tree,
                    Object value, boolean bSelected, boolean bExpanded,
                            boolean bLeaf, int iRow, boolean bHasFocus )
    {
        // Find out which node we are rendering and get its text
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
        String  labelText = (String)node.getUserObject();

        this.bSelected = bSelected;

        // Set the correct foreground color
        if( !bSelected )
            setForeground( Color.black );
        else
            setForeground( Color.white );
            ....
    }
```

Comment: I need interclass actionListener. See the code that I put to my question